# How to avoid using MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT on camera intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm trying to allow my user to pick a picture from the phone gallery or to take a picture with the camera.
I wrote a piece of code working really well on my Samsung S6

```
private void openPictureIntent() {
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_CODE);
    }
```

Then I tried it on a Nexus 5X and my app crashed. I learned that the intent retrieved in onActivityResult is null with some devices. The solution is to give the uri where to save the image taken with the camera. I implemented it and my code became

```
private void openPictureIntent() {
        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Directory" + File.separator);
        dir.mkdirs();
        final String fname = UUID.randomUUID() + ".jpg";
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(dir, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
        new File(outputFileUri.getPath()).delete();

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SELECT_PICTURE_CODE);
    }
```

This is working but I'm not satisfied. I would like my photo to be stored with other camera photo and not in a special directory. How could I achieve that ?

Comment: save image Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES directory

Comment: The gallery intent do not show the photos from the picture directory (same goes for the DCIM repository) on my device and I would like to have the same result on every devices

Comment: Images stored in `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` and `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` are perfectly eligible to be scanned by the `MediaStore` and therefore show up in gallery-type apps. They will be indexed automatically eventually, and developers can use `MediaScannerConnection` to add particular files to the `MediaStore` as they are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I learned that the intent retrieved in onActivityResult is null with some devices.

It is supposed to be `null` for all camera apps. Some camera app developers fail to read [the documentation for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).

> I would like my photo to be stored with other camera photo and not in a special directory

That is not supported by `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: If I understand well your answer, in conclusion there is no solution if I want to use ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE ?

Comment: @Tibo: There are thousands of camera apps, many of which support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. You have no way of knowing where "with other camera photo" will be for thousands of camera apps. You can store your photos in a likely spot (e.g., `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`), but that is it.

Comment: Thank for your answer !